# How can I diagnose why Avalonia ItemsControl is not populating at runtime, but shows up in designer?

Tags: c#, xaml, avaloniaui

### Question

I have created a simple Avalonia UI Windows application on .NET 5. The designer correctly evaluates my codebehind and displays a ItemsControl with the correct number of elements. When I run the code, the ItemsControl is not populated. How can I diagnose why this isn't working?

### Details

I am using the following codebehind to populate my ViewModels:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    var vm = new MainWindowViewModel();

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        var panelVm = new TestPanelViewModel();

        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            panelVm.AllTests.Add(new TestItemViewModel
            {
                TestName = $"Test{j}-{i}"
            });
        }
        vm.Panels.Add(panelVm);

    }
    AvaloniaXamlLoader.Load(this);

    this.DataContext = vm;
}
```

This is correctly evaluated by the designer, and the preview displays what I'd expect:

[image]

Unfortunately when I run the code, I have an empty window:

[image]

I don't see any errors in my Debug output:

```
'TestRunner.exe' (CoreCLR: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.4\System.Private.CoreLib.dll'. 
'TestRunner.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\vchel\Documents\GitHub\IntegrationTesting\TestRunner\TestRunner\bin\Debug\net5.0\TestRunner.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'TestRunner.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.4\System.Runtime.dll'. 
'TestRunner.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\vchel\Documents\GitHub\IntegrationTesting\TestRunner\TestRunner\bin\Debug\net5.0\Avalonia.DesktopRuntime.dll'. 
'TestRunner.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\vchel\Documents\GitHub\IntegrationTesting\TestRunner\TestRunner\bin\Debug\net5.0\Avalonia.Controls.dll'. 
'TestRunner.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.4\netstandard.dll'. 
'TestRunner.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\vchel\Documents\GitHub\IntegrationTesting\TestRunner\TestRunner\bin\Debug\net5.0\Avalonia.Base.dll'. 
'TestRunner.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.4\System.ObjectModel.dll'. 
'TestRunner.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\vchel\Documents\GitHub\IntegrationTesting\TestRunner\TestRunner\bin\Debug\net5.0\Avalonia.Styling.dll'. 
'TestRunner.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\vchel\Documents\GitHub\IntegrationTesting\TestRunner\TestRunner\bin\Debug\net5.0\Avalonia.Input.dll'. 
'TestRunner.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\vchel\Documents\GitHub\IntegrationTesting\TestRunner\TestRunner\bin\Debug\net5.0\Avalonia.Interactivity.dll'. 
'TestRunner.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\vchel\Documents\GitHub\IntegrationTesting\TestRunner\TestRunner\bin\Debug\net5.0\Avalonia.Layout.dll'. 
'TestRunner.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\vchel\Documents\GitHub\IntegrationTesting\TestRunner\TestRunner\bin\Debug\net5.0\Avalonia.Visuals.dll'. 
'TestRunner.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\vchel\Documents\GitHub\IntegrationTesting\TestRunner\TestRunner\bin\Debug\net5.0\Avalonia.Animation.dll'. 
'TestRunner.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.4\System.ComponentModel.Primitives.dll'. 
'TestRunner.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.4\System.Collections.dll'. 
'TestRunner.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\vchel\Documents\GitHub\IntegrationTesting\TestRunner\TestRunner\bin\Debug\net5.0\Avalonia.Desktop.dll'. 
'TestRunner.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\vchel\Documents\GitHub\IntegrationTesting\TestRunner\TestRunner\bin\Debug\net5.0\Avalonia.ReactiveUI.dll'. 
'TestRunner.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.4\System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll'. 
'TestRunner.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\vchel\Documents\GitHub\IntegrationTesting\TestRunner\TestRunner\bin\Debug\net5.0\Avalonia.Win32.dll'. 
'TestRunner.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\vchel\Documents\GitHub\IntegrationTesting\TestRunner\TestRunner\bin\Debug\net5.0\Avalonia.MicroCom.dll'. 
'TestRunner.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.4\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll'. 
'TestRunner.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.4\System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll'. 
'TestRunner.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.4\System.Collections.Concurrent.dll'. 
'TestRunner.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\vchel\Documents\GitHub\IntegrationTesting\TestRunner\TestRunner\bin\Debug\net5.0\Avalonia.Skia.dll'. 
'TestRunner.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\vchel\Documents\GitHub\IntegrationTesting\TestRunner\TestRunner\bin\Debug\net5.0\System.Reactive.dll'. 
'TestRunner.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.4\System.Threading.dll'. 
'TestRunner.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.4\System.Private.Uri.dll'. 
'TestRunner.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.4\System.Linq.dll'. 
'TestRunner.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.4\System.ComponentModel.dll'. 
'TestRunner.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.4\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll'. 
'TestRunner.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.4\System.Xml.XDocument.dll'. 
'TestRunner.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.4\System.Private.Xml.Linq.dll'. 
'TestRunner.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.4\System.Private.Xml.dll'. 
'TestRunner.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.4\System.Threading.Thread.dll'. 
'TestRunner.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.4\System.Memory.dll'. 
'TestRunner.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.4\System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll'. 
'TestRunner.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.4\System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll'. 
'TestRunner.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\vchel\Documents\GitHub\IntegrationTesting\TestRunner\TestRunner\bin\Debug\net5.0\Avalonia.OpenGL.dll'. 
'TestRunner.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.4\Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll'. 
'TestRunner.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\vchel\Documents\GitHub\IntegrationTesting\TestRunner\TestRunner\bin\Debug\net5.0\SkiaSharp.dll'. 
'TestRunner.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\vchel\Documents\GitHub\IntegrationTesting\TestRunner\TestRunner\bin\Debug\net5.0\Splat.dll'. 
'TestRunner.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\vchel\Documents\GitHub\IntegrationTesting\TestRunner\TestRunner\bin\Debug\net5.0\ReactiveUI.dll'. 
'TestRunner.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.4\System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll'. 
LogHost: Initializing to normal mode (.cctor)
'TestRunner.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.4\System.Threading.Timer.dll'. 
'TestRunner.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\vchel\Documents\GitHub\IntegrationTesting\TestRunner\TestRunner\bin\Debug\net5.0\Avalonia.Markup.Xaml.dll'. 
'TestRunner.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\vchel\Documents\GitHub\IntegrationTesting\TestRunner\TestRunner\bin\Debug\net5.0\Avalonia.Themes.Fluent.dll'. 
'TestRunner.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\vchel\Documents\GitHub\IntegrationTesting\TestRunner\TestRunner\bin\Debug\net5.0\Avalonia.Markup.dll'. 
'TestRunner.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.4\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll'. 
'TestRunner.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\vchel\Documents\GitHub\IntegrationTesting\TestRunner\TestRunner\bin\Debug\net5.0\Avalonia.Diagnostics.dll'. 
'TestRunner.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\vchel\Documents\GitHub\IntegrationTesting\TestRunner\TestRunner\bin\Debug\net5.0\runtimes\win\lib\netcoreapp2.0\System.Drawing.Common.dll'. 
'TestRunner.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.4\System.Drawing.Primitives.dll'. 
'TestRunner.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.4\System.Buffers.dll'.
```

My code doesn't seem to throw any exceptions, and I am able to step through the ViewModel-building code as expected.

What else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the default template assigns a view model automatically, and this was overwriting my view model:

```
public override void OnFrameworkInitializationCompleted()
{
    if (ApplicationLifetime is IClassicDesktopStyleApplicationLifetime desktop)
    {
        desktop.MainWindow = new MainWindow
        {
            DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel(),
        };
    }

    base.OnFrameworkInitializationCompleted();
}
```